# SwiftUI - How to make images from URLs with different sizes fit the frame?

Tags: image, url, swiftui, uiimage, favicon

I'm trying to have a series of favicons downloaded from the internet, and then inserted in a squared-shaped frame. However, they have different sizes, and nor with scaledToFit() or scaledToFill() they seem to fix the issue.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var websites = ["https://www.reddit.com/favicon.ico", "https://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico", "https://www.instagram.com/favicon.ico", "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico", "https://www.netflix.com/favicon.ico", "https://www.amazon.com/favicon.ico"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(websites, id: \.self) { wbs in
                    Image(uiImage: try! UIImage(withContentsOfUrl: URL(string: wbs)!)!)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .strokeBorder(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1.0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.clear))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(withContentsOfUrl url: URL) throws {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        self.init(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is that all icons fill the frame the same way. For example, in the screenshot I attached, the favicons of Reddit and Instagram look good, while Facebook is too small and Amazon or Netflix are too big.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Add the resizable modifier

Comment: as mentioned use `.resizable()` just before the `.frame(...)` 
and don't do the try! and force unwrappings inside the Image(....), 
that's just asking for troubles.

Comment: @workingdog Thank you! Yes, I added the force unwrapping only for this example, to avoid pasting too much code that had nothing to do with my question! But thank you anyway for pointing it out, it could be a useful tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the

```
.resizable()
```

Modifier to Image